# Code detects MMX/SSE/AVX but not AVX2

Tags: delphi

I want to have universal way of detecting specific CPU features. For this task I've created this function which takes EAX leaf number,Register name and bit number and returns true or false. It works fine for MMX/SSEx/AVX (EAX=1) but it does not detect AVX2 (EAX=7).

CPU: i5-4670k 
OS: Windows 7

```
DetectCPUFeature('1','EDX',23) //DETECTS MMX CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','EDX',25) //DETECTS SSE CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','EDX',26) //DETECTS SSE2 CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','ECX',0)  //DETECTS SSE3 CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','ECX',9)  //DETECTS SSSE3 CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','ECX',19) //DETECTS SSE4.1 CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','ECX',20) //DETECTS SSE4.2 CORRECTLY
DetectCPUFeature('1','ECX',28) //DETECTS AVX CORRECTLY

DetectCPUFeature('7','EBX',5) //DOES NOT DETECT AVX2!
```

.

```
function DetectCPUFeature(EAX_Leaf_HEX,Register_Name:string;Bit:byte):boolean;
var _eax,_ebx,_ecx,_edx,EAX_Leaf,_Result: Longword;
    x:integer;
    Binary_mask:string;
    Decimal_mask:int64;
begin

  EAX_Leaf:=HexToInt(EAX_Leaf_HEX);
  Binary_mask:='1';
  for x:=1 to Bit do Binary_mask:=Binary_mask+'0';
  Decimal_mask:=BinToInt(Binary_mask);

  if AnsiUpperCase(Register_Name)='EDX' then
  begin
    asm
      mov eax,EAX_Leaf // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID
      db $0F,$A2 // db $0F,$A2 = CPUID instruction
      mov _Result,edx
    end;
  end;

  if AnsiUpperCase(Register_Name)='ECX' then
  begin
    asm
      mov eax,EAX_Leaf
      db $0F,$A2
      mov _Result,ecx
    end;
  end;

  if AnsiUpperCase(Register_Name)='EBX' then
  begin
    asm
      mov eax,EAX_Leaf
      db $0F,$A2
      mov _Result,ebx
  end;
 end;

 if (_Result and Decimal_mask) = Decimal_mask then DetectCPUFeature:=true 
 else DetectCPUFeature:=false;  

end;
```

Answer (score 6):

This sort of code is very dubious, mixing asm with Pascal code. Your code, in the `asm` blocks modifies registers and fails to restore them. That could easily be conflicting with the compiler's register usage. My strong advice to you is that you should never mix asm and Pascal in this way. Always use pure Pascal or pure asm.

What you need is a function that will perform the `CPUID` instruction and return you all the registers in a structure. You can then pick out what you want from that using Pascal code.

In addition, as @J... points out, you need to specify the sub-leaf value in the `ECX` register before invoking the `CPUID` instruction. That is a requirement for a number of the more recently added `CPUID` arguments.

This is the function you need:

```
type
  TCPUID = record
    EAX: Cardinal;
    EBX: Cardinal;
    ECX: Cardinal;
    EDX: Cardinal;
  end;

function GetCPUID(Leaf, Subleaf: Cardinal): TCPUID;
asm
  push  ebx
  push  edi
  mov   edi, ecx
  mov   ecx, edx
  cpuid
  mov   [edi+$0], eax
  mov   [edi+$4], ebx
  mov   [edi+$8], ecx
  mov   [edi+$c], edx
  pop   edi
  pop   ebx
end;
```

I've written this for 32 bit code, but if you need to support 64 bit code also that support is easy enough to add.

```
function GetCPUID(Leaf, Subleaf: Integer): TCPUID;
asm
{$IF Defined(CPUX86)}
  push  ebx
  push  edi
  mov   edi, ecx
  mov   ecx, edx
  cpuid
  mov   [edi+$0], eax
  mov   [edi+$4], ebx
  mov   [edi+$8], ecx
  mov   [edi+$c], edx
  pop   edi
  pop   ebx
{$ELSEIF Defined(CPUX64)}
  mov   r9,rcx
  mov   ecx,r8d
  mov   r8,rbx
  mov   eax,edx
  cpuid
  mov   [r9+$0], eax
  mov   [r9+$4], ebx
  mov   [r9+$8], ecx
  mov   [r9+$c], edx
  mov   rbx, r8
{$ELSE}
  {$Message Fatal 'GetCPUID has not been implemented for this architecture.'}
{$IFEND}
end;
```

With this at hand you can call `CPUID` passing any value as input, and retrieve all 4 registers of output, with which you can then do whatever you please.

Your code to create a bitmask is extremely inefficient and very far from idiomatic. Use `1 shl N` to create a value with a single bit set, in position `N`.

Code like this:

```
if (_Result and Decimal_mask) = Decimal_mask then DetectCPUFeature:=true 
else DetectCPUFeature:=false;
```

is also some way from idiomatic. That would normally be written like this:

```
DetectCPUFeature := value and mask <> 0;
```

You might end up with a wrapper function that looks like this:

```
type
  TCPUIDRegister = (regEAX, regEBX, regECX, regEDX);

function GetCPUIDRegister(CPUID: TCPUID; Reg: TCPUIDRegister): Cardinal;
begin
  case Reg of
  regEAX:
    Result := CPUID.EAX;
  regEBX:
    Result := CPUID.EBX;
  regECX:
    Result := CPUID.ECX;
  regEDX:
    Result := CPUID.EDX;
  end;
end;

function CPUFeatureEnabled(Leaf, Subleaf: Cardinal; Reg: TCPUIDRegister; Bit: Integer): Boolean;
var
  value: Cardinal;
begin
  value := GetCPUIDRegister(GetCPUID(Leaf, Subleaf), Reg);
  Result := value and (1 shl Bit) <> 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

While David's answer is excellent, the reason the function fails is that the `ECX` register is not set to zero (required for fetching extended info in the CPUID call).

See : [How to detect New Instruction support in the 4th generation Intel® Core™ processor family](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/405250/how-to-detect-new-instruction-support-in-the-4th-generation-intel-core-processor-family.pdf)

where AVX2 is found by (emphasis mine)

> CPUID.(EAX=07H, **ECX=0H**):EBX.AVX2[bit 5]==1

The following correctly returns the extended information and identifies AVX2 support.

```
 if AnsiUpperCase(Register_Name)='EBX' then
  begin
    asm
      push ecx         { push ecx to stack}
      mov ecx, 0       { set ecx to zero}
      mov eax,EAX_Leaf
      db $0F,$A2
      mov _Result,ebx
      pop ecx          { restore ecx}
  end;
```

The other `asm` functions have the same error as `ECX` is required to be zero for those calls also.

Comment: `ECX` is 32 bits in size, even on a 64bit machine, so the `tmp` variable should be a 32bit variable to match. `NativeInt` is not suitable for that purpose, since it is 64 bits in a 64bit executable. Use `(U)Int32` or `Cardinal` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, good point.  Probably should just use the stack, really.

Answer (score -2):

taken from Synopse Informatique:

```
type
  /// the potential features, retrieved from an Intel CPU
  // - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits
  TALIntelCpuFeature =
   ( { in EDX }
   cfFPU, cfVME, cfDE, cfPSE, cfTSC, cfMSR, cfPAE, cfMCE,
   cfCX8, cfAPIC, cf_d10, cfSEP, cfMTRR, cfPGE, cfMCA, cfCMOV,
   cfPAT, cfPSE36, cfPSN, cfCLFSH, cf_d20, cfDS, cfACPI, cfMMX,
   cfFXSR, cfSSE, cfSSE2, cfSS, cfHTT, cfTM, cfIA64, cfPBE,
   { in ECX }
   cfSSE3, cfCLMUL, cfDS64, cfMON, cfDSCPL, cfVMX, cfSMX, cfEST,
   cfTM2, cfSSSE3, cfCID, cfSDBG, cfFMA, cfCX16, cfXTPR, cfPDCM,
   cf_c16, cfPCID, cfDCA, cfSSE41, cfSSE42, cfX2A, cfMOVBE, cfPOPCNT,
   cfTSC2, cfAESNI, cfXS, cfOSXS, cfAVX, cfF16C, cfRAND, cfHYP,
   { extended features in EBX, ECX }
   cfFSGS, cf_b01, cfSGX, cfBMI1, cfHLE, cfAVX2, cf_b06, cfSMEP, cfBMI2,
   cfERMS, cfINVPCID, cfRTM, cfPQM, cf_b13, cfMPX, cfPQE, cfAVX512F,
   cfAVX512DQ, cfRDSEED, cfADX, cfSMAP, cfAVX512IFMA, cfPCOMMIT,
   cfCLFLUSH, cfCLWB, cfIPT, cfAVX512PF, cfAVX512ER, cfAVX512CD,
   cfSHA, cfAVX512BW, cfAVX512VL, cfPREFW1, cfAVX512VBMI);

  /// all features, as retrieved from an Intel CPU
  TALIntelCpuFeatures = set of TALIntelCpuFeature;

var
  /// the available CPU features, as recognized at program startup
  ALCpuFeatures: TALIntelCpuFeatures;

{**}
type
 _TRegisters = record
   eax,ebx,ecx,edx: cardinal;
 end;

{***************************************************************}
procedure _GetCPUID(Param: Cardinal; var Registers: _TRegisters);
{$IF defined(CPU64BITS)}
asm // ecx=param, rdx=Registers (Linux: edi,rsi)
  .NOFRAME
  mov     eax, ecx
  mov     r9, rdx
  mov     r10, rbx // preserve rbx
  xor     ebx, ebx
  xor     ecx, ecx
  xor     edx, edx
  cpuid
  mov     _TRegisters(r9).&eax, eax
  mov     _TRegisters(r9).&ebx, ebx
  mov     _TRegisters(r9).&ecx, ecx
  mov     _TRegisters(r9).&edx, edx
  mov     rbx, r10
end;
{$else}
asm
  push    esi
  push    edi
  mov     esi, edx
  mov     edi, eax
  pushfd
  pop     eax
  mov     edx, eax
  xor     eax, $200000
  push    eax
  popfd
  pushfd
  pop     eax
  xor     eax, edx
  jz      @nocpuid
  push    ebx
  mov     eax, edi
  xor     ecx, ecx
  cpuid
  mov     _TRegisters(esi).&eax, eax
  mov     _TRegisters(esi).&ebx, ebx
  mov     _TRegisters(esi).&ecx, ecx
  mov     _TRegisters(esi).&edx, edx
  pop     ebx
@nocpuid:
  pop     edi
  pop     esi
end;
{$ifend}

{******************************}
procedure _TestIntelCpuFeatures;
var regs: _TRegisters;
begin
  regs.edx := 0;
  regs.ecx := 0;
  _GetCPUID(1,regs);
  PIntegerArray(@ALCpuFeatures)^[0] := regs.edx;
  PIntegerArray(@ALCpuFeatures)^[1] := regs.ecx;
  _GetCPUID(7,regs);
  PIntegerArray(@ALCpuFeatures)^[2] := regs.ebx;
  PByteArray(@ALCpuFeatures)^[12] := regs.ecx;
end;

initialization
  _TestIntelCpuFeatures;
```

Comment: I guess that code is protected by [MPL/GPL/LGPL tri-license](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25). Ping @ArnaudBouchez.

Comment: This post contravenes that license